# clojure newbie how to call methods of a java object

Tags: clojure

I'm trying the following

```
  (def myMap (HashMap.))
  (doto (myMap) (.put "a" 1) (.put "b" 2))
```

I get as a result:

```
Reflection warning, core.clj:20:3 - call to method put can't be resolved (target class is unknown).
Reflection warning, core.clj:20:3 - call to method put can't be resolved (target class is unknown).
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the brackets around `myMap`:

```
(doto myMap (.put "a" 1) (.put "b" 2))
```

`(myMap)` will attempt to call `myMap` as a function.

Answer (score 2):

Not really. The compiler is just warning you that its emitting code that uses reflection.  You can type hint Clojure to get rid of this:

```
(def ^HashMap myMap (HashMap.))
(doto myMap (.put "a" 1) (.put "b" 2))
```

**Update**: Ha, I didn't read the error message very well :)  However, as soon as you remove the parens from `(myMap)` you'll get an actual reflection warning (assuming `(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)`) which can be resolved by my example above.